# VS Code Snippets - Regex multiple operations

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I've tried for day to get snippets to work with regex, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a way of doing it.

The usecase is writing LaTeX, specifically sections with automatic labeling. I have some issues with labelling, since LaTeX doesn't allow certain danish characters in the labels. Therefore, I would like for the snippet to take care of the replacements itself, as well as some other formatting. That means that I want the following:

1. Make everything lowercase
2. Change letters "æ", "ø" and "å" to "ae", "oe" and "aa"
3. Remove special characters (so characters are only a-z and 0-9)
4. Change spaces to "_"

Lastly, I would like to highlight the "transformed" text, so I can change it to something different if I need to (in case of duplicate labels).

The snippet would look like the following:

```latex
\section{$1} \label{sec:${2:$1(after regex)}
```

Hope that makes any sense at all

The transformation would do the following

Ørne og Mus!   ->   oerne_og_mus

This is doable in Textmate with the following snippet

```latex
\section{${1:section name}}
\label{sec:${2:${1/(\w+)(\W+$)?|\W+/${1:?${1:/asciify/downcase}:_}/g}}}
```

But this is not compatible with VS code. Can this somehow be altered to work with VS code?

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of before and after text.  I don't follow your snippet `\section....`.

Comment: Yes, of course.

So, the transformation would do the following:

Ørne og Mus!   ->   oerne_og_mus

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: try this snippet:**

```
"latex labels": {
  "prefix": "_ll",
  "body": [
      "\\section{$1}",
      "\\label{sec:${2:${1/(\\w*)((æ)|(ø)|(å)|(é)|(\\s+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]))/${1:/downcase}${3:+ae}${4:+oe}${5:+aa}${6:+e}${7:+_}/gi}}}",
    ],
    "description": "Transform to latex labels"
},
```

If you have more Danish characters you will have to add them individually - vscode does not support the `/asciify` transform.

---

Previous Answer:

I really don't think you can do it in one regex.  Which means a normal snippet will not work.  A macro can run as many snippet transforms as you want though.

Using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings.json:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.latexLabelTransform",
      "sequence": [
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
              "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(æ)|(ø)|(å)/${1:+ae}${2:+oe}${3:+aa}/gi}"
          }
        },
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
              "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}"
          }
        },
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
              "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[^a-z0-9 ]//g}"
          }
        },
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
              "snippet": "\\section {$CLIPBOARD} \\label{sec:${2:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s/_/g}}}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.latexLabelTransform" }
},
```

If you are starting with the text, for example `Ørne og Mus!` see the following demo:

[image: latex snippet transform]

---

The transformed part is selected as seen in the demo.  Cursor at end of text before triggering the macro.  I could probably get it to work starting with `\section {yourTextHere}` as well if need be.

I tried to get it to work as a regular snippet but it doesn't seem to be a way to get the multiple transforms that you want done in a single transform.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Mark

Really cool solution. I'll check it out tomorrow. The reason i asked the question was because i was able to get the described behaviour in TextMate with the snippet:

\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/(\w+)(\W+$)?|\W+/${1:?${1:/asciify/downcase}:_}/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)

This was able to do the above listed commands, but the snippet doesn't work inside VS Code. Can the regex code somehow be altered to work inside VS Code?

Comment: Try the snippet I added to the top of the answer.  It might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I might have found a solution finally that works as a snippet

```
"\\section{$1}",
"\\label{sec:${2:${1/(æ)|(ø)|(å)|(é)|( +)|[^A-Za-z0-9]/${1:+ae}${2:+oe}${3:+aa}${4:+e}${5:+_}/g}}}",
```

Only a couple of issues i've found.

1. I have to manually add accented letters to the list such as é
2. No downcase
3. If there is a string say "! ! ", it gets replaced with two underscores instead of 1, as there is a break in between the spaces.

Anyone have an idea of how that could be changed? Or where I can even find a good resource for this type of regex (I haven't been able to find one)

Comment: Did you see my edit in the answer.  It addresses your issues 1 and 2.